# Figure Position

Tags: wrapfigure

Can anyone help me with this problem? I have done various things including finding answers on internet, but I did not find a solution.

I want to put the image in the text on the left in the first paragraph.

```
\begin{center}
    {\bf \large  XXXXX}\\
\end{center}
{\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.3\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{1518604125388.JPG}
\end{wrapfigure} 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cc f gggg hhhh dddd ffffffffff gggggggggg bbbbbbbbbb nnnnnnnnnnnnnn bbbbbbbbbb aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cc f gggg hhhh dddd ffffffffff gggggggggg bbbbbbbbbb nnnnnnnnnnnnnn bbbbbbbbbb aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cc f gggg hhhh dddd ffffffffff gggggggggg bbbbbbbbbb nnnnnnnnnnnnnn bbbbbbbbbb.

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cc f gggg hhhh dddd ffffffffff gggggggggg bbbbbbbbbb nnnnnnnnnnnnnn bbbbbbbbbb aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cc f gggg hhhh dddd ffffffffff gggggggggg bbbbbbbbbb nnnnnnnnnnnnnn bbbbbbbbbb aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb cc f gggg hhhh dddd ffffffffff gggggggggg bbbbbbbbbb nnnnnnnnnnnnnn bbbbbbbbbb.
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please complete your example with the documentclass and packages you're using?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is a small advice for your future posts: you should use dummy text from `lipsum` or `blindtext` instead of "aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccc".

Comment: Thank you so much, now i get the answere.

I use \newline in end paragraph

Comment: Remove the braces around `wrapfig`.

Answer (score 1):

That is a job for [`wrapfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig?lang=en) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{The title}}
\author{The author} \date{The date}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Birds}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AfroditDione142: Please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) then, by clicking the tick icon above.